# How to fit an enlarged h1 within a div without the text overlapping?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I've been trying to create a responsive layout for my h1 tag. It works perfectly fine when I don't change its `font-size`, but as soon as I enlarge the font-size the text overlaps the `background-image` after shrinking the window size. Is there a solution to fix this problem?

Here's my code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: orangered;
}

.main-page-font {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, blue, grey);
    padding: 16em 10em;
    background-size: cover;
}

.headers h1,
.headers h3 {
    color: azure;
}

.headers h1 {
    font-size: 8.5em;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="main-page-font">
        <div class="headers">
            <h1>This is a long header for this page</h1>
            <h3>Fit me within this space please</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do to fix your problem is change the CSS file to this and check the result on different screen sizes:

1. Give `body` an height that later can be changed when you add more elements in your HTML file
2. Give `main-page-font` a width and a height to encapsulate the headers and prevent overflow
3. Give `main-page-font` a `display: inline-block;` to prevent it from taking extra unwanted space

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: orangered;

    height: 100vh;
}

.main-page-font {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, blue, grey);
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
}

.headers h1,
.headers h3 {
    color: azure;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 15em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-page-font">
        <div class="headers">
            <h1>This is a long header for this page</h1>
            <h3>Fit me within this space please</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will fix your problem!

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I gave the container a width (in %) of 80%, and gave the child element another width of 100% (which basically covers 100% width of its parent). This worked perfectly fine for me.